# Odds of three of a kind in Yahtzee (5 six sided dice)

Tags: probability

So if I have five six sided dice what is the probability of getting three of a kind? Ie. 44452 or 63353.

I worked it out as

${{6 \choose 1}}$ ways of choosing the for the triple

${{5 \choose 3}}$ ways of choosing the dice for the triple

${{5 \choose 2}}$ ways of choosing the values for the single numbers

${{2 \choose 2}}$ ways of choosing the dice single numbers. (Only 1 one way of choosing 2 dice from remaining 2 dice).

$6^5$ total results from five six sided dice

So $$\frac{{{6 \choose 1}}{{5 \choose 3}}{{5 \choose 2}}{{2 \choose 2}}}{6^5}$$

And I get $\frac{25}{324}$...but it seems the actual answer is $\frac{25}{162}$ so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you count your "good" results, you count the outcomes $(4,4,4,2,5)$ and $(4,4,4,5,2)$ as a single result. But they are both counted when you say that the overall number of possible results is $6^5$. The point is, that you consider the dice being distinguishable. There fore the last point should read

- $\binom 21$ ways to choose the die for the first single number, $\binom 11$ way to choose the die for the second single number

So you have the double number of "good" results, leaving you with an overall probability of $\frac {25}{162}$.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these answers appear incorrect.

$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 = 0.1929012346$
where the first factor is the number of triples and the rest is a Bernoulii trial.

For the math using a Markov chain: http://datagenetics.com/blog/january42012/index.html.

For a simple computational experiment:

```
$ cat dice.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

num=100000000

print "# dice,# kind,p,p+"

for numdice in range(5,7):  #number of dice: 4, 5, 6
    for numgood in range(3,numdice+1):  #number of kind: 3, 4, ... numdice
        kill=0
        killp=0
        for i in range(num):  # do the rolls
            vals = [0] * 6
            for j in range(numdice):
                vals[random.randint(0,5)] += 1

            if max(vals) == numgood:
                kill += 1
            if max(vals) >= numgood:
                killp += 1
        print numdice,numgood,1.0*kill/num,1.0*killp/num
```

```
$  ./dice1.py 
# dice,# kind,p,p+
5 3 0.19296403 0.21304555
5 4 0.01928664 0.02005203
5 5 0.00077289 0.00077289
6 3 0.31503221 0.36717084
6 4 0.04822759 0.05222477
6 5 0.00385591 0.00398596
6 6 0.00012805 0.00012805
```

Comment: The original question appears to be asking about a three of a kind as distinct from a full house -- that is, $\{3, 3, 3, 5, 6\}$ should count, whereas $\{3, 3, 3, 5, 5\}$ should *not*. I think that's the discrepancy between your answer and theirs.

Comment: Do agree my solution includes full house. Also appears you're correct since the probability of full house is 300/7776. If you subtract that off my answer, you get the original answer. Thanks.